# Getting wrong output when swapping elements in an array

Tags: c, arrays

> **The Problem I am trying to solve is:**
>
> Consider an array of characters. start scanning each character one
>   by one from both left and right. If both the scanned characters is an
>   alphabet then swap them in the array.
>
> **Example:**
>
> If the array is `! w , s t u # p a b` then I will start scanning from
>   both left and right. ie first I will scan `!` and `b` since both are
>   not alphabets I will not swap. Then I will move to `w` and `a` , since
>   both are alphabets I will swap them. I will continue this process till
>   i reach the middle of the array.

**My code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {

    int p,q,len,i;
    char s[100],temp;

    //ask the length of string
    printf("Enter the number of chars:\n");
    scanf("%d",&len);

    //get each char in the string and store in array s[]
    printf("Enter %d chars:\n",len);
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
        scanf("%c",&s[i]);

    //start scanning char by char from both sides
    p=0;
    q=len-1;

    while(p<=q)
    {
        // swap chars if both p and q points to a letter
        if(isalpha(s[p]) && isalpha(s[q]))
        {
        temp=s[p];
        s[p]=s[q];
        s[q]=temp;
        }
        //increment p to move towards right
        p++;
        //decrement q to move towards left
        q--;
    }

    //print all chars in the array
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
        printf("%c",s[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

**My input:**

```
10
!w,stu#pab
```

**My expected output:**

```
!a,sut#pwb
```

**The output I get:**

```
!w,tsu#pa
```

Why am I getting wrong output? Where is the bug?

Comment: why dont you just read the string as `scanf("%s",s);`

Comment: i tried that, noting changes

Comment: You didn't null terminate the string while reading it.  Print it; it will be different from what you expect.

Comment: You should print out the string after you've read it and before you try to change it.  You'll notice it's missing a character... That's because the `\n` left in the buffer after you read the length is the first character you read.  use `" %c"` instead to skip leading whitespace.

Comment: yup that worked...thanks

Comment: Ninja is correct as to the cause, but it would be a whole lot easier to replace your `scanf` calls with: `printf("Enter the chars:\n"); fgets(s,sizeof(s),stdin); len = strlen(s); len -= 1; s[len] = 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {

    int p,q,len,i;
    char s[100],temp;

    //ask the length of string
    printf("Enter the number of chars:\n");
    scanf("%d",&len);

    //get each char in the string and store in array s[]
    printf("Enter %d chars:\n",len);
    scanf("%s",&s[i]);

    //start scanning char by char from both sides
    p=0;
    q=len-1;

    while(p<=q) {
        // swap chars if both p and q points to a letter
        if(isalpha(s[p]) && isalpha(s[q])) {
            temp=s[p];
            s[p]=s[q];
            s[q]=temp;
        }
        //increment p to move towards right
        p++;
        //decrement q to move towards left
        q--;
    }

    //print all chars in the array
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
        printf("%c",s[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **What about** explaining what was wrong (thus _replying_ to the answer)?